# Segfault with RIP-relative addressing on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, assembly

I have a simple piece of assembly code that works correctly on Mac OS X (x86-64) but not on Linux (x86-64):

```
.data
.align 4

foo: .quad 1,2

.text

.globl fun
fun:
movapd foo(%rip), %xmm1
ret
```

Called from a simple C program:

```
int main(void){
  fun();
  return 0;
}
```

What happens on the Mac is that the xmm1 register is filled with the data at location foo i.e. in GDB:

```
(gdb) p $xmm1
$2 = {
...
v2_int64 = {2, 1}, 
uint128 = 0x00000000000000020000000000000001
}
```

When I run the same code under Linux it segfaults - it seems that the foo label corresponds to 0x0:

```
> objdump -d asm.o
...

Disassembly of section .text:
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   66 0f 28 0d 00 00 00   movapd 0x0(%rip),%xmm1
...
```

Can someone explain why this occurs and what I can do to avoid it?

Cheers

- Iain

Comment: When it segfaults what is the value of RIP and the value of foo?  Is it 16-byte aligned like the movapd instruction requires?

Comment: On the linux version I get %rip = 0x4004e8 and on the Mac %rip = 0x100000f35.  I'm not sure how to examine the value of foo in GDB (it's a label) but using nm on the executable gives 0000000000601018 on Linux and 00000001000001060 on the Mac

Comment: You are correct it's an alignment problem - If I use movupd instead I get the correct behaviour on Linux.  Unfortunately I the actual code I'm working on I use xorpd (movapd) was just an example, which I don't think has an unaligned variant.  I could put in the extra instruction to load unaligned into an extra register, but if there is some way to force the alignment to be correct that would be best since this idiom occurs throughout the code.  Also, it doesn't explain why objdump shows my label as 0x0...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the mainline gnu binutils, on i386 and x86_64, the `.align n` directive tells the assembler to align to n bytes (however, on some architectures and platforms, it has other meanings.  Consult the documentation for full details).

On OS X, the `.align n` directive tells the assembler to align to 2^n bytes.  This is why your code works on the Mac.

If you want consistent cross-platform behavior, use the `.p2align` directive instead, which is supported on both platforms, and tells the assembler to align to 2^n bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The segfault happens because of misalignment. A 4 Byte alignment isn't sufficient for movapd, you need 16 Byte `.align 16` at least.

You see `0(%rip)` in objdump, because the code isn't relocated yet. The runtime linker will replace it with the correct offset when you execute it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  All working now.  I do recall reading somewhere that align is specified as number of bits of zeros i.e. align 4 gives 2^4=16 byte alignment.  Can't find it now...

Comment: This is the case for the gcc -falign-xxx switches. The ".align" pseudo instruction accepts the alignment in bytes.

Comment: Never use .align, always .p2align or .balign, to avoid ambiguity between 2^n vs. n on different targets.